# Django foreignkey insert data

Tags: django

Why i cant get the ID and save it to the database? eventhough i already display it in my html.

in my window html, i already display the id of payment

```
  <h3><b>Payment Type</b></h3>
<select id="payments" name ="payments" onchange="payment(this.value)" style="border-radius:8px 8px 8px 8px; outline: none; padding:4px 10px 4px 10px" required>
    <option value="0">-- Payment Type --</option>
   {% for paymentschedule in payment %}
    <option value="{{paymentschedule.Payment_Type.id}}" name ="payments">{{paymentschedule.Payment_Type.id}} {{paymentschedule.Payment_Type}}</option>
    {% endfor%}
</select>
```

[image]

That 1 number is the ID

this is my logic on how to save in my database

```
id = request.POST.get('payments')
payment = PaymentType(id=id)


V_insert_data = StudentsEnrollmentRecord(
    Payment_Type=payment,
        )
V_insert_data.save()
```

this is the error says

[image]

This is my models

```
class StudentsEnrollmentRecord(models.Model):
    Pending_Request = [
       ('Active', 'Active'),
       ('Inactive', 'Inactive'),
    ]
    Payment_Type = models.ForeignKey(PaymentType,on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True ,blank=True)

class PaymentType(models.Model):
    Description = models.CharField(max_length=500,blank=True)
    Display_Sequence = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
```

did i miss something?

this is the fulltraceback

[image]

**UPDATE**

when i tried this

```
paymentid = request.POST.get('payments')
payment = PaymentType.objects.filter(id=paymentid)

V_insert_data = StudentsEnrollmentRecord.objects.create(
      Payment_Type=payment
        )
```

I receive this error

[image]

Comment: What is `'strands'` exactly? Looks like a field that you did not show?

Comment: i already show display the id of strand in my html, just like in the picture,

Comment: my problem is icant get that id to save it to my database

Comment: but here it is `payments`. Obfuscating data is not a problem, but you are obfuscating too much I think to receive help.

Comment: sir please check again my question, specially the traceback and error,

Comment: how do i solve this error?

Comment: based on the traceback, you did not modify the view propery, since here `save()` is replaced with `.create()`

Comment: how do i modify my view? i didnt get the id of payment in my html

Comment: remove the `name="payments"` from the `<option>` tags, this should only be in the `<select>` tag.

Comment: I get the same error :(

Comment: But you still write something like `payment = PaymentType(id=id)`? What if you remove that?

Comment: i didnt get any error but the result is 'None' . why?

Comment: is it a bug? i didnt receive any error but the data save in my database is 'None'

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214667/discussion-between-justin-and-willem-van-onsem).

Answer (score 0):

Please do not create an object, you can simply save the data with:

```
payment_id = request.POST.get('payments')
V_insert_data = StudentsEnrollmentRecord.objects.create(
    Payment_Type_id=payment_id
)
```

Comment: Please post the *full* traceback and the entire view.